# Magento: how to update reference in block, using value from configuration?

Tags: magento, block

That's problem: I have some block, which can change his position, regarding on some value from configuration.

```
<default>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="st1/sq1" name="right.topS22" template="st1/sq1.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

I have (for example, in block class the value "left" or "right" from configuration). I would to update name="" of reference, using this value.

May be, it's wrong approach and I'm digging not in right place.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with CMS > Widget.

Widgets / Instance widgets can be configured dynamically to place at left, right, footer, main content area etc..